# Magento 2 reopen a closed order

Tags: magento2, rest-api, order-status

How can I reopen a closed order through REST API or programmatically to enable the shipping option again on the order? I have tried changing order status to new and processing still no result. Any other way how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

try this PUT /V1/orders/create

```
'entity' => [
                'entity_id'=> 1,
                'increment_id' => '000000015',
                'status'=> 'pending',
]
```

Comment: The order status gets changed but it is still closed.

Comment: what does that mean, is it changed to pending or not?

Comment: yes status is changed to pending but the order is still 'close' in admin panel

Comment: it might be because, you may have already generate an invoice for that order,

Comment: Yes, Actually I have created credit memo also for half order but now I want to deliver remaining order. is there any other way to do so?

Comment: If you have credit memo for the orders then it might not be possible with api's to reopen them, the only way left is either to do it programmatically or by making changes in sales order tables. Also, making changes in tables is not recommended.