# Magento 2: How to change order status from Complete back to Processing

Tags: magento2, order-status

Is there a way to change the order status back to being Processing when order is already in Complete status? Is there some code way or MySQL way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240891/49186

Comment: No, but I will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way to do this. If you manually alter the database status data for the order you will break the *order / invoice / ship* core logic of Magento and although you might change the admin order status it is likely to other cause problems or errors for that order.