# Request Order Status Change

Tags: orders, order-status, order-grid

Is there a way to change status from Shipped to Processing? I accidentally click the Ship status. Please help

Comment: I think this might may help you regarding this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332181/magento-2-how-to-change-order-status-from-complete-back-to-processing

Comment: If this helps you please mark this an answer